# Keyboard appearance in ScrollView (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, keyboard

I have set up a `ScrollView` and a `TextView`:

```
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView {
        // ...
    }
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
        TextInputCellView() { value in
            vm.send(text: value)
        }
}
```

When the keyboard appears or resizes, the `ScrollView` resizes perfectly (as can be seen from the indicators in the video), however the item which was displayed at the bottom before the keyboard appeared should still be in the view after the appearance (same for when the keyboard size changes).
How can i achieve that ?

[image]

Comment: What i did in the end: i rotated the scrollview, as well as the content by 180°. This way, the automatic scroll up works when the keyboard appears or updates its size. Furthermore you can insert new items on top without losing the scroll position (what comes in handy when implementing a chat).